# Marlin 2.0.x bugfix 2nd extruder not working

Tags: marlin, ultimaker-cura, diy-3d-printer, repetier, repetier-host

I am using the SKR PRO board on a dual extruder 3D printer. I have tried Curaengine and Slic3r in Repetier-host. The printer firmware is handling the offset fine (it prints in the right spot for extruder 2 when it switches extruders) but it won't extrude any filament. When I type in T1 and manually extrude with the buttons in reetier-host it extrudes just fine. I have let it go for several layers without seeing any extrusion from the 2nd extruder. The main extruder works fine and doesn't extrude while the 2nd one is selected. Here is some of the g-code from curaengine slicing the dual extruder calibration cube.

```
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 15.01
; Default start code
G28 ; Home extruder
G1 Z15 F100
M107 ; Turn off fan
G90 ; Absolute positioning
M82 ; Extruder in absolute mode
M190 S50
; Activate all used extruder
M104 T0 S200
M104 T1 S200
G92 E0 ; Reset extruder position
; Wait for all used extruders to reach temperature
M109 T0 S200
M109 T1 S200
;Layer count: 100
;LAYER:0
M107
G0 F6000 X-10.960 Y3.540 Z0.200
;TYPE:SKIRT
G1 F1800 X-10.960 Y12.456 E0.26689
G1 X-23.956 Y12.456 E0.65592
G1 X-23.956 Y-0.540 E1.04494
G1 X-15.040 Y-0.540 E1.31183
G1 X-15.040 Y-23.540 E2.00032
G1 X12.040 Y-23.540 E2.81093
G1 X12.040 Y3.540 E3.62155
G1 X-10.960 Y3.540 E4.31003
G0 F6000 X-11.320 Y3.180
G1 F1800 X-11.320 Y12.096 E4.57693
G1 X-23.596 Y12.096 E4.94440
G1 X-23.596 Y-0.180 E5.31187
G1 X-14.680 Y-0.180 E5.57876
G1 X-14.680 Y-23.180 E6.26725
G1 X11.680 Y-23.180 E7.05631
G1 X11.680 Y3.180 E7.84537
G1 X-11.320 Y3.180 E8.53386
G1 F2400 E3.53386
G0 F6000 X-10.960 Y-10.540
;TYPE:WALL-INNER
G1 F2400 E8.53386
G1 F1800 X-10.960 Y-19.460 E8.80087
G1 X-2.040 Y-19.460 E9.06788
G1 X-2.040 Y-10.540 E9.33490
G1 X-10.960 Y-10.540 E9.60191
G0 F6000 X-11.320 Y-10.180
;TYPE:WALL-OUTER
G1 F1800 X-11.320 Y-19.820 E9.89047
G1 X-1.680 Y-19.820 E10.17904
G1 X-1.680 Y-10.180 E10.46760
G1 X-11.320 Y-10.180 E10.75617
G0 F6000 X-10.411 Y-10.665
;TYPE:SKIN
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-11.088 E10.77405
G0 F6000 X-10.833 Y-11.597
G1 F1800 X-9.902 Y-10.665 E10.81349
G0 F6000 X-9.393 Y-10.665
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-12.106 E10.87447
G0 F6000 X-10.833 Y-12.615
G1 F1800 X-8.884 Y-10.665 E10.95700
G0 F6000 X-8.374 Y-10.665
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-13.124 E11.06109
G0 F6000 X-10.833 Y-13.633
G1 F1800 X-7.865 Y-10.665 E11.18674
G0 F6000 X-7.356 Y-10.665
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-14.142 E11.33393
G0 F6000 X-10.833 Y-14.651
G1 F1800 X-6.847 Y-10.665 E11.50267
G0 F6000 X-6.338 Y-10.665
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-15.161 E11.69298
G0 F6000 X-10.833 Y-15.670
G1 F1800 X-5.829 Y-10.665 E11.90484
G0 F6000 X-5.320 Y-10.665
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-16.179 E12.13824
G0 F6000 X-10.833 Y-16.688
G1 F1800 X-4.811 Y-10.665 E12.39319
G0 F6000 X-4.302 Y-10.665
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-17.197 E12.66969
G0 F6000 X-10.833 Y-17.706
G1 F1800 X-3.792 Y-10.665 E12.96776
G0 F6000 X-3.283 Y-10.665
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-18.215 E13.28738
G0 F6000 X-10.833 Y-18.724
G1 F1800 X-2.774 Y-10.665 E13.62854
G0 F6000 X-2.265 Y-10.665
G1 F1800 X-10.833 Y-19.234 E13.99127
G0 F6000 X-10.423 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-11.075 E14.34086
G0 F6000 X-2.165 Y-11.584
G1 F1800 X-9.914 Y-19.333 E14.66890
G0 F6000 X-9.405 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-12.093 E14.97540
G0 F6000 X-2.165 Y-12.602
G1 F1800 X-8.896 Y-19.333 E15.26034
G0 F6000 X-8.386 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-13.111 E15.52372
G0 F6000 X-2.165 Y-13.620
G1 F1800 X-7.877 Y-19.333 E15.76555
G0 F6000 X-7.368 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-14.130 E15.98580
G0 F6000 X-2.165 Y-14.639
G1 F1800 X-6.859 Y-19.333 E16.18452
G0 F6000 X-6.350 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-15.148 E16.36168
G0 F6000 X-2.165 Y-15.657
G1 F1800 X-5.841 Y-19.333 E16.51730
G0 F6000 X-5.332 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-16.166 E16.65137
G0 F6000 X-2.165 Y-16.675
G1 F1800 X-4.823 Y-19.333 E16.76389
G0 F6000 X-4.314 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-17.184 E16.85486
G0 F6000 X-2.165 Y-17.693
G1 F1800 X-3.804 Y-19.333 E16.92427
G0 F6000 X-3.295 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-18.203 E16.97211
G0 F6000 X-2.165 Y-18.712
G1 F1800 X-2.786 Y-19.333 E16.99839
G0 F6000 X-2.277 Y-19.333
G1 F1800 X-2.165 Y-19.221 E17.00314
G92 E0
G1 F2400 E-5.00000

T1

G0 F6000 X-14.500 Y3.000
;TYPE:SUPPORT
G1 F2400 E0.00000
G1 F1800 X-14.500 Y8.916 E0.17709
G1 X-20.416 Y8.916 E0.35418
G1 X-20.416 Y3.000 E0.53127
G1 X-14.500 Y3.000 E0.70836
G0 F6000 X-14.878 Y2.940
G1 F1800 X-14.439 Y3.379 E0.72695
G0 F6000 X-14.439 Y3.945
'''
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the Left and Right extruders turn the opposite direction so once I inverted E1 in marlin it is working fine.

Comment: Note that this is dependant on how the hotends and extruders are mounted. To this extent, it would have helped to show a photo of the extruders - glad you managed to figure it out yourself.